# Difference between calling .cfm and .cfc with JQuery Ajax?

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, frameworks, coldfusion-11, cfc

I'm working on the new system and there are few things that are different from what I used to see. Basically there is an JQuery ajax call with "POST" type and url pointing to `.cfm` page. The `.cfm` page will return `html` table.

After talking to lead developer he mentioned that this method is more efficient. This way calling `.cfm` we do not create new instance each time we make a call. The other way if we use .cfc and call a function new instance will be created each time. I do not know everything behind the screen and deep layers of ColdFusion.

One other thing he mentioned this way it's better since we do not use any frameworks. I have been working with ColdFusion for the past 4 years and what I seen in the past is JQuery Ajax calling `component.cfc` with specific `method` name. The data is returned and table is built dynamically. I was wondering if someone knows more about this and why the `.cfm` might be better than calling `.cfc`.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but the comments of your lead developer might be referring to browser caching of the .cfm file.

Comment: @DanBracuk Is there any performance difference on ColdFusion side? He was talking about web services and case when there is no framework. I'm not sure since I always used `.cfc` files and `methods`.

Comment: I think this might firmly fall into the realm of "It depends.", and any answer you get may not apply to future readers' situations. What exactly does "more efficient" mean? Personally, I think it would be "more efficient" across the entire stack to call a .cfc webservice that returns some JSON data that is used to build the table that you serve to the end-user. Like you described. Though "POST" suggests something different than "GET". And depending on your action, a .cfm may be a "better" choice. And it sounds like your dev may be talking about caching. But again, What's "better"? It Depends.

Comment: I would ask your lead dev to explain to you why .cfm is better than .cfc in this situation. Especially since it's different than what you've seen in the past. Again, there may be something about this particular situation that makes .cfm the better choice, and it helps you help the system if you understand.

Comment: @Shawn Overall he talked about creating new instance each time we call function in `.cfc`. That seems like something that can cause some efficiency issues since these instances will sit in cold fusion memory. I'm not an expert in this area and I want to check if someone else would be able to provide more details. I personally like using .cfc and returning JSON format data. That seems like a good option.

Comment: Is your dev resistant to CFCs because of this belief? If your dev is concerned about the memory management of CFC use, then there may be some other technology issues that need to be addressed. As far as I know, Java uses (and reuses) memory for CFCs pretty efficiently. Also, look through https://www.cfguide.io/optimizing-tuning-scaling-coldfusion-jvm/ and https://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion_performance.html.

Comment: @Shawn I was able to gather more information and here are few things. For example if you send request and there are 3000 records. The formatted HTML payload is around 700KB, but if we transfer that through JSON and then use JS to organize the data in the table, build the table it will add more time and code. That's one of the reason why .cfm has advantage over .cfc way. You can correct me if I'm wrong but that was his argument. I like using .cfc wth JSON since all front end and back end is separate. Nice and clean way to keep the code easy for maintenance.

Comment: How the data gets transferred is a different topic.  It has nothing to do with the cfc vs cfm choice.

Comment: Is there a need to return 3000 records, or can that be paginated? How many columns of data are you selecting and what's the size of those columns? Sending more data over the network to save a little processing time may not always be the best if someone has to pay for that bandwidth. Or if 20 people request the page at the same time. Also, why POST instead of GET? And there's caching. Without knowing what this application is doing, I can't really say why cfm might be better, but I usually tend to agree with you in keeping concerns separate.

Comment: Back in CF 8 days instantiating a CFC was slow and expensive. That's why frameworks like ColdSpring were introduced that cached CFC instancers. This has changed over the years.

Comment: Of course, a CFC can return a string that contains a HTML fragment, too.

Comment: @Shawn I agree that paging should be used in case when you have more than few hundred records. There are 10 columns and they are all ranging from 5 to 50 characters. Why POST instead of GET I'm not sure. I always use GET method. They used POST in their code to call .cfm page and return HTML. This application delivers data in JQuery Datatable. I'm wondering how to weight when to use paging?  Should I use that and show 50 records per page and then on each click get another 50 with ajax?

Comment: Datatables is built to do pagination & handling large data, including letting you choose how many records your want to display per page. It's pretty flexible. RE: GET vs POST, they can both do the same thing, just differently. Generally, GET is when you are requesting data and nothing will change, and POST is sending data to the server where something might change. Both will return a response. GET is sent in URLs; POST is sent in headers. There are a lot of considerations and comparing the 2 is pretty much a research topic on its own. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Since this is essentially contacting ColdFusion to get data to plug back into DataTables, then I would probably disagree with not using a CFC-based webservice, returning JSON or some other light-weight payload. DataTables doesn't need an HTML page built for it. That's what DataTables does with the data you send back to it. I think the benefits a CFC offers far outweigh most concerns about using a .cfm instead. But again, the particulars of your application and infrastructure may make a .cfm more practical. So I'm back to "It Depends".

Comment: Considering most REST API frameworks use CFCs, I would say CFC is the correct choice, although I must say that for a long time, I used simple CFM templates with XHTTP requests...

Comment: But, with a REST API, the request usually does not directly hit a CFC. It is sent to a template that will then use PATH_INFO to direct it to the relevant verb method of a component. In this case, the CFC framework will already have been instantiated & cached in the Application scope. So, this is a slightly different scenario, but one that maybe you should consider.

Comment: @CharlesRobertson Can you please provide an example or article about REST API? I'm using JQuery/Ajax to send a request to CFC method. Not sure if that is the best way now days.

Comment: @expresso_coffee Yes. Please go to Taffy.io: http://docs.taffy.io/3.2.0

Comment: @CharlesRobertson I remember Taffy. It was recommended on one of the CF Conferences. Thank you.

Comment: Taffy.io is really easy to set up and allows you to create a professional, modern REST API, using Coldfusion. I use it with Angular 6, but you can just as easily use it with jQuery or Vanilla JS XHTTP. Good luck!

Comment: @CharlesRobertson I was just about to ask you if it's recommended for Single Page App framework. Since you are using Taffy in combination with Angular it should be fine I guess.

Comment: @CharlesRobertson Also I have found FW/1 framework and seems very popular in Adobe community. I'm not sure about major differences between Taffy and FW/1.

Comment: FW1 is an MVC framework, for creating entire websites or custom CMS, where as is Taffy is just a REST API framework. You can use both together!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*To long for a comment*

I agree with what the others have already said. There is no specific answer because it always depends on more things than just this bit of code. Having said that...

I found this from the Adobe documentation [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/building-and-using-coldfusion-components/about-coldfusion-components.html) which seems relevant. Below is an excerpt from that documentation. I highlighted in **bold** the part which seems relevant. Notice the part about after the CFC is instantiated. You can read more at the link.

> When to use CFCs
>
> You can use CFCs in the following ways:
>
> - Developing structured, reusable code
> - Creating web services
> - Creating Flash Remoting elements
> - Using asynchronous CFCs
>
> Developing structured, reusable code
>
> CFCs provide an excellent method for developing structured applications that separate display elements from logical elements and encapsulate database queries. You can use CFCs to create application functionality that you (and others) can reuse wherever needed, like user-defined functions (UDFs) and custom tags. If you want to modify, add, or remove component functionality, you make changes in only one component file. 
>   CFCs have several advantages over UDFs and custom tags. These advantages, which CFCs automatically provide, include all of the following:
>
> - The ability to group related methods into a single component, and to group related components into a package
> - Properties that multiple methods can share
> - The This scope, a component-specific scope
> - Inheritance of component methods and properties from a base component, including the use of the Super keyword
> - Access control
> - Introspection for CFC methods, properties, and metadata
>     **CFCs have one characteristic that prevents them from being the automatic choice for all code reuse. It takes relatively more processing time to instantiate a CFC than to process a custom tag. In turn, it takes substantially more time to process a custom tag than to execute a user-defined function (UDF). However, after a CFC is instantiated, calling a CFC method has about the same processing overhead as an equivalent UDF. As a result, do not use CFCs in place of independent, single-purpose custom tags or UDFs. Instead, use CFCs to create bodies of related methods, particularly methods that share properties.
>     For more information about UDFs, custom tags, and other ColdFusion code reuse techniques, see Creating ColdFusion Elements.**
>
> Creating web services
>
> ColdFusion can automatically publish CFC methods as web services. To publish a CFC method as a web service, you specify the access="remote" attribute in the method's cffunction tag. ColdFusion generates all the required Web Services Description Language (WSDL) code and exports the CFC methods. For more information on creating web services in ColdFusion, see Using Web Services.

Now I don't always trust the Adobe documentation as they have a nasty habit of just carrying forward the existing documentation from version to version. So who knows when this was originally written and if it is still true. And this is specific to Adobe's ColdFusion, Lucee is likely better at handling this but I'm not sure.

That document also refers to this document - [Selecting among ColdFusion code reuse methods](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/creating-coldfusion-elements/selecting-among-coldfusion-code-reuse-methods.html). I will include that info here as well.

> The following table lists common reasons to employ code reuse methods and indicates the techniques to consider for each purpose. The letter P indicates that the method is preferred. (There can be more than one preferred method.) The letter A means that the method provides an alternative that is useful in some circumstances.
>   This table does not include CFX tags. You use CFX tags only when it is best to code your functionality in C++ or Java. For more information about using CFX tags, see Using CFX tags.

[image]